# How to let a helper script (Bash/Python/Ruby/Perl) execute a complicated command?

Tags: python, ruby, linux, bash, perl

Please see my question at the bottom.

This is the command I would like to have executed in a Perl script using `system()`

```
zfs send tank/Test0@snap | mbuffer -4 -O 10.10.47.47:8023
```

but I get this error

```
mbuffer: warning: error connecting to 10.10.47.47:8023: Connection refused
mbuffer: error: unable to connect to 10.10.47.47:8023
mbuffer: fatal: no output left - nothing to do
```

which is misleading, as I can execute the command in a terminal, and it works fine.

So now I have become creative to find a way to work around this limitation. Putting the command in a file and do

```
system("ssh localhost /tmp/test");
```

works, but having to SSH to localhost and make temp files are not good. The `ssh localhost` is needed otherwise I get the same error.

To avoid the temp file creation I tried to make a "parser file"

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
$1 | $2
```

which is call `pipe.sh` and then in Perl do

```
my $a = 'zfs send tank/Test0@snap';
my $b = "mbuffer -4 -O 10.10.47.47:8023";
system("pipe.sh $a $b");
```

but the `pipe.sh` executes `zfs | send`.

My next idea was

```
my $c = "zfs send tank/Test0\@snap \| mbuffer -4 -O 10.10.47.47:8023";
system("pipe.sh $c");
```

with `pipe.sh` become

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
$@
```

but this treats each as a separate command. I.e. `zfs`, then `send` and so on.

**Question**

I have run out of ideas how to execute that command without making a temp file, which is bad, as `tank/Test0` is actually a variable inside a for-loop, so it would result in many writes.

Instead of calling a bash script I am open for executing a Ruby or Python script, if they can handle this better than Bash.

**Update**

If I from the terminal do

```
perl -e'system "bash", "-c", q{zfs send tank/Test0@snap | mbuffer -4 -O 10.10.47.47:8023}'
```

then it works, but doing the same from within the script

```
system("bash", "-c", q{zfs send tank/Test0@snap | mbuffer -4 -O 10.10.47.47:8023});
```

gives me (with mbuffer verbose 5 enabled)

```
mbuffer: Verbose = 5
mbuffer: total # of phys pages: 1132576 (pagesize 4096)
mbuffer: default buffer set to 22651 blocks of 4096 bytes
mbuffer: getting address info for 10.10.47.47:8023
mbuffer: warning: error connecting to 10.10.47.47:8023: Connection refused
mbuffer: error: unable to connect to 10.10.47.47:8023
mbuffer: allocating memory for 22651 blocks with 4096 byte (90604 kB total)...
mbuffer: creating semaphores...
mbuffer: opening input...
mbuffer: direct I/O hinting failed for input: Invalid argument
mbuffer: fatal: no output left - nothing to do
```

**Update 2**

This actually works!

```
system("ssh", "localhost", q{zfs send tank/Test0@snap | mbuffer -4 -v 5 -O 10.10.47.47:8023});
```

I get the following error with the most verbose enabled, but works for some reason.

```
mbuffer: Verbose = 5
mbuffer: total # of phys pages: 1130435 (pagesize 4096)
mbuffer: default buffer set to 22608 blocks of 4096 bytes
mbuffer: getting address info for 10.10.47.47:8023
mbuffer: successfully connected to 10.10.47.47:8023
mbuffer: set TCP send buffer size to 1048576
mbuffer: allocating memory for 22608 blocks with 4096 byte (90432 kB total)...
mbuffer: creating semaphores...
mbuffer: opening input...
mbuffer: direct I/O hinting failed for input: Invalid argument
mbuffer: direct I/O hinting failed for output to 10.10.47.47:8023: Invalid argument
mbuffer: checking if we have a controlling terminal...
mbuffer: registering signals...
mbuffer: starting threads...
mbuffer: checking output device...
mbuffer: no device on output stream
mbuffer: checking input device...
mbuffer: no device on input stream
mbuffer: outputThread: starting output on 10.10.47.47:8023...
mbuffer: inputThread: starting with threadid 3...
mbuffer: inputThread: last block has 2640 bytes
mbuffer: inputThread: exiting...
mbuffer: outputThread: last block has 2640 bytes
mbuffer: outputThread: syncing 10.10.47.47:8023...
mbuffer: syncing unsupported on 10.10.47.47:8023: omitted.
mbuffer: outputThread: finished - exiting...
mbuffer: waiting for senders...
mbuffer: joining sender for 10.10.47.47:8023

summary: 46.0 KiByte in  0.0 sec - average of 22.9 MiB/s
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65630/discussion-on-question-by-jasmine-lognnes-how-to-let-a-helper-script-bash-pytho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mbuffer developer has this to say about the error

> Concerning the warning related to I/O hinting - these warning can
>   safely be ignored. mbuffer is just telling you that no I/O hinting is
>   possible. I/O hinting just gives tips to the operating system what
>   kind of I/O sequence is coming, so that the OS is able to tune its
>   operation for that specific scenario. I/O hinting is implemented
>   differently for most OSs...

As for the actual problem, then `Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall` is the solution as seen in [this](https://github.com/oetiker/znapzend/blob/master/lib/ZnapZend/ZFS.pm) module, which does exactly what I am trying to do.